# Express Regex to exclude files from route

Tags: regex, express

I'm trying to write a route  in Express that excludes urls ending with extensions:

```
router.get(/.*(?<!(\..*))$/, function(req, res, next) {

});
```

But even when my example is accepted https://regexr.com/41qus, Express reject it.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Variable length lookbehind, I'd suspect?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You should remove `'`s from the regex literal. Then, there is a lookbehind that might not be supported by your JS environment. The whole current regex is equal to `/^[^.]*$/`

Comment: Ah, sorry, the quotes aren't there in the actual code, is a type in the question. If you check it in then RegExr it works, so I suppose that it is ok; but Express doesn't accept it.

Comment: Because of the lookbehind. Use `/^[^.]*$/` or `/^(?!.*\.[a-zA-Z]+$).*/`

Comment: Express can't use lookbehinds? Ook…

Comment: So, does `/^(?!.*\.[a-zA-Z]+$).*/` or `/^(?!.*\.[a-zA-Z]+$)/` work?

Comment: `/^[^.]*$/` did the trick :)